# Sum of a binomial type series

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

From Binomial Theorem we know $(p+q)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}\left( p \right)^r  \left( q \right)^{n-r}$.

Then how to find out the sum for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( 1- \sum_{r=i}^{n} \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}\left( p \right)^r  \left( q \right)^{n-r} \right)$ when $n$ is finite?
Furthermore, want to know the value of this summation as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Rate of convergence usually does not apply to finite sums

Comment: For $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: What is it even converging too?  $(p+q)^n\to0\text{ or }\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, for example.

Comment: In other words, the question doesn't make sense as is.  You could ask for us to calculate the sum, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!

Comment: I think it diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Since, $p+q=1$ so $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( 1- \sum_{r=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}\left( p \right)^r  \left( q \right)^{n-r}\right) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: No, I do not think that is true.  From my perspective, it is positive and increasing as $n\to\infty$, so it can't converge to $0$.  Consider $p=q=1/2$

Comment: Did I mention welcome to the site and that the MathJax handbook is found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: It will definitely converge to 0 if the bracketed summation becomes $\sum_{r=0}^{n}$ instead of $\sum_{r=i}^{n}$.

Comment: Thanks for such sarcastic welcoming! Very rare in wise wisdom.

Comment: Your welcome for the welcome.  Anyways, for the case $p=q=1/2$, see that $\sum_{r=i}^n=1-\sum_{r=0}^{i-1}$.  So then the $1$'s cancel, and we're left with something that definitely does not add up to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum can be written in a nice formula, but the limit as $n$ approaches infinity is messy.

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( 1- \sum_{r=i}^{n} \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} p^r  q^{n-r} \right)&=n-\sum_{i=1}^{n}  \sum_{r=i}^{n} \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}p ^r   q ^{n-r}
\\&=n-\sum_{r=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^r\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}p^r q^{n-r}
\\&=n-\sum_{r=1}^nr\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}p^r q^{n-r}
\\&=n-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}p^r q^{n-r}
\\&=n-\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{(n-1)!\,n}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}p^r q^{n-r}
\\&=n-n\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{(n-1)!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}p^r q^{n-r}
\\&=n-n\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{r!(n-r-1)!}p^{r+1} q^{n-r-1}
\\&=n-np\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{r!\big((n-1)-r\big)!}p^r q^{(n-1)-r}
\\&=n-np(p+q)^{n-1}
\\&=n\big(1-p(p+q)^{n-1}\big).
\end{align}
$$ $$
*Case 1.* $p+q\gt 1.$ So $(p+q)^{n-1}\to +\infty$ as $n\to\infty.$

*Subcase 1(a).* $p\le 0.$  Then $n\big(1-p(p+q)^{n-1}\big)\to+\infty$ as $n\to\infty.$

*Subcase 1(b).* $p\gt 0.$ Then $n\big(1-p(p+q)^{n-1}\big)\to -\infty$ as $n\to\infty.$
$$ $$
*Case 2.* $p+q=1.$ So $(p+q)^{n-1}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty.$

*Subcase 2(a).* $p\lt 1.$  Then $n\big(1-p(p+q)^{n-1}\big)\to+\infty$ as $n\to\infty.$

*Subcase 2(b).* $p=1.$ Then $n\big(1-p(p+q)^{n-1}\big)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty.$

*Subcase 2(c).* $p\gt 1.$  Then $n\big(1-p(p+q)^{n-1}\big)\to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty.$

$$ $$

*Case 3.* $-1 \lt p+q\lt 1.$ Then $(p+q)^{n-1}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty.$  So in this case, there are no subcases, and we just get that $n\big(1-p(p+q)^{n-1}\big)\to+\infty$ as $n\to\infty.$
$$ $$
*Case 4.* $p+q=-1.$ So $(p+q)^{n-1}$ alternates between $+1$ and $-1$ as $n$ increases.

*Subcase 4(a).* $-1\lt p \lt 1.$ Then $n\big(1-p(p+q)^{n-1}\big)\to +\infty$ as $n\to\infty.$

*Subcase 4(b).* $p\le -1$ or $p\ge 1.$ There are various possibilities here, based on whether $p\lt -1, p=-1, -=1,$ or $p\gt 1,$ but you can check that in all those cases the terms $n\big(1-p(p+q)^{n-1}\big)$ for even $n$ behave differently for large $n$ from those for odd $n,$ so that $n\big(1-p(p+q)^{n-1}\big)$ doesn't approach a limit as $n\to\infty,$ not even $+\infty$ or $-\infty.$
$$ $$
*Case 5.* $p+q\lt -1.$  In this case $(p+q)^{n-1}$ alternates in sign as $n$ increases, with the values for even $n$ approaching $-\infty,$ and the values for odd $n$ approaching $+\infty.$

*Subcase 5(a).* $p=0.$ Then $n\big(1-p(p+q)^{n-1}\big)\to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty.$

*Subcase 5(b).* $p\ne 0.$ Then $n\big(1-p(p+q)^{n-1}\big)$ has no limit, with the even terms approaching either $+\infty$ or $-\infty,$ and the odd terms approaching $-\infty$ or $+\infty,$ respectively.

So we can summarize all this by writing

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( 1- \sum_{r=i}^{n} \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} p^r  q^{n-r}\right)=
\\\begin{cases}
\scriptsize{\text{undefined (no limit, not even }+\infty\text{ or }-\infty)},&\text{ if }(p+q\lt -1\text{ and }p\ne 0)\text{ or }(p+q=-1\text{ and either }p\le -1\text{ or }p\ge 1),
\\-\infty,&\text{ if }(p+q\gt 1\text{ and }p\gt 0)\text{ or }(p+q=1\text{ and }p \gt 1)\text{ or }(p=0\text{ and }q\lt -1),
\\0,&\text{ if }p=1\text{ and }q=0,
\\+\infty,&\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your such elaborate and very great answer! Simply outstanding!!